# Do you remove or leave in unused methods in objective c (like viewDidAppear)

Tags: objective-c

I am fairly new to Objective C and wonder if most people remove or don't remove unused methods. For example, when I create a UIViewController, there are stub methods that I often don't use, and I want to remove them.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove them if you'd like. However, if you leave them in, make sure a call to `super` is performed in each method so that you don't lose the default implementation. This means you want your empty (for now) method to extend, not override, the functionality of that same method in parent class.

Edit: Having a method implementation that does nothing other than call the same method on super is equivalent to removing the method all together. Super will then be called by default.

Comment: I was thinking that that was the case - having to leave in the super. I like the idea of removing the unused classes.

Comment: @user796709 removing the method will cause only the super class implementation to be called. having and method with only a super call is equivalent to removing the method

Answer (score 0):

I remove them along with all dead code. They just clutter the working code and reduce readability.